# How can I select rows with an extra column joined from the same table

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have a table like this:

```
id | path      | name | date       | data
---+-----------+------+------------+-----
1  | Docs      | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | aaa0
2  | Docs/1000 | Text | 2022-01-11 | AAA0
3  | Docs      | 1001 | 2022-02-02 | aaa1
4  | Docs/1001 | Text | 2022-02-12 | AAA1
```

How can I select all rows with path 'Docs' and add the date of the corresponding 'Text', i.e:

```
id | path | name | date       | date_of_text | data
---+------+------+------------+--------------+-----
1  | Docs | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-11   | AAA0
3  | Docs | 1001 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-12   | AAA1
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  Select what?  Do you just want to know how to select from a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with self join -

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.path, T1.name, T1.date, T2.date date_of_text, T2.data
  FROM table_name T1
  LEFT JOIN table_name T2 ON T1.name = SUBSTRING(path, POSITION("/" IN path) + 1, LENGTH(path))
 WHERE T1.path = 'Docs'
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I just need "GROUP BY T1.id" on my bigger data set

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this including

correlated sub query

```
select t.*,id % 2 ,(select date from t t1 where t1.ID = t.id + 1) datetext
from t
where id % 2 > 0;
```

self join

```
select t.*,t.id % 2 , t1.date
from t
join t t1 on t1.ID = t.id + 1
where t.id % 2 > 0;
```

Aggregation

```
select min(id) id,min(path) path,min(date) date,upper(data) data ,max(date) datetext
from t
group by t.data;
```